# To add code html in all day cells III

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

From this example:

```
`Demo Full Calenda` http://jsfiddle.net/eladerezador/k712ps6u/
```

I have decided to change the way do it, because is dificult, to add content in the cell the calendar table .

I'm about to solve it, but I need a final aid.

I want to add one event, which it is composed of three elements, two list (icons and numbers vertical ul) and one text (planificación semanal),

The problem, is the text, It is shown creeped out  in cell, the table has to look like this:

[image]

The list of icons and numbers, looks good, the problem is when you add the text "weekly schedule" at the event.

Thanks,

Comment: Just set a smaller width for the icons `.fc-event-icons`

Comment: I finally resolved this theme, miracle, the solution is in the property "overflow" of the classes .fc-day-grid-event .fc-content, have to be overflow: visible;

Thanks,